# Recieved An "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" through an Int Optional Variable from UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I received An "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" through an Int Optional Variable from UITextField:

meterTimeEntered was declared as:

`var meterTimeEnetered = Int?()`

backgroundTap Function - A Function when user tap the background and it triggers startTime Function - I use this function after user have either enter a number into UITextField or exit from the UITextField which lays on top of MKMapView:

```
 @IBAction func backgroundTap(sender: UIControl) {

    if  meterTime > 0{
        return
    } else {
        if meterTimeTextField.text != nil{
            meterTimeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            startTime()
            timerDisplay.text = String(displayMeterTime)
            self.parkItButton.hidden = true
            self.UnparkButton.hidden = false
            self.mapView.hidden = false
            self.findItButton.hidden = false
            self.timerDisplay.hidden = false

        }
    }
            //self.meterTimeTextField.hidden = true
            //meterTimeTextField = nil
 //            } else {
//               // nilTextFieldEntryAlert()
//            }
  }
```

startTime Function - `meterTimeEntered = Int(meterTimeTextField.text!)!` is where i got the error:

```
func startTime(){
        meterTimeEntered = Int(meterTimeTextField.text!)!
        if meterTimeEntered != 0 {
            meterTime = (meterTimeEntered! * 60)
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.timerDisplay.hidden = false
            self.meterTimeTextField.hidden = true
        } else {
            nilTextFieldEntryAlert()
        }
}
```

[Unexpected found nil when pass into meterTimeEntered from meterTimeTextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QWcJ.png)

[A Function when user tap the background and it triggers startTime Function - I use this function after user have either enter a number into UITextField or exit from the UITextField which lays on top of MKMapView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKiDF.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. My goldfish memory can't handle it to actually help you.

Comment: Can you please print `meterTimeTextField.text` to the console as the first line of `startTime()`

Comment: @Jojodmo output of meterTimeTextField.text is meterTimeTextField.text Optional("")

Comment: How about testing whether things are nil and responding based on the result rather than using ! in an attempt to force them?

Comment: @JTan That's why then - you're trying to force the unwrapping of a nil value, `meterTimeTextField.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to avoid using `!` if you can. It should only be used in cases where you've previously tested the value is not `nil`.

You would be better to use `??` and supply a default value for the case where the variable is `nil`.

For example, with your crashing line, you could to:

```
meterTimeEntered = Int(meterTimeTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0
```

This removes two `!` cases, which removes two possible crash points. `.text` could be `nil`, so in this case, we'll use a default value of `""`. The second `??` is because `Int()` could fail, so you default to `0`. You may want a better default based on what your code is actually doing.

But this means you'll never crash here, which is the goal.

As an aside, my colleagues and I have come to call the `!` a `crashbang` (similar to a `#!` `hashbang`). Every time you see one in code, assume you have a possible crash there.

Comment: I think using `guard` would be a better approach since having the value of `meterTimeTextField.text` as an Int is mandatory.

Comment: @Dave Wood - whenever i tap the background, once the app is loaded, it triggers the backgroundTap function. I actually do want meterTimeTextField.text to be nil so can i possibly assign meterTimeTextField.text = " " or meterTimeTextField = nil before checking meterTimeText.field != nil ?

Comment: @Eendje sure `guard` could work, but would likely lead to code duplication in this case since you'd still have an `else` in the `if`. Using a default value prevents that duplication.

Comment: @JTan Not sure what you're saying there, but, the point is that you can't use `!` if the value could be `nil`. You'll crash in that case. So you have to check for `nil` first and handle it in some way. My example above is just one way, that keeps your code mostly the same. You could check for `nil` explicitly if you like.